# Chrome: `fetch` takes too long

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, babeljs, polyfills, babel-polyfill

## Update:

I changed the API from `fetch` to `XMLHttpRequest` and I still see the problem.

According to the console logs the delay is between "**readyState 1**"(i.e. OPENED) and "**readyState 2**"(i.e HEADERS_RECEIVED).

Also, maybe it is worth mentioning, that in Firefox it works fine.

---

I would appreciate a couple of pointers on how to debug why the call to `fetch()` takes 1 sec in chrome.

According to "network" tab the request took only 12ms. However in my logs and the "timeline" tab the `fetch()` takes 1.06 sec. (Screenshots below).

Any tips on how to figure out what is stalling the `fetch()`?

Network Tab screenshot:
[image]

Timeline Tab screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Do you get any further information when you hover or click on the network panel entry?

Comment: In the "Network" Tab, where the entry is normal, I get extra information, but everything looks fine there. In the "Timeline" Tab, I don't get anything extra if I click on the long entry.

Comment: second screenshot belongs to which tab?

Comment: @Abhijeet sorry if it was not clear. The second screenshot is for the "Timeline" Tab, for the exact same request.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all extensions, and/or tested in Incognito mode? Also, check out `about:net-internals`, it may provide some clues as to what's going on exactly.

Comment: @robertklep Yes, I have tried with all extensions disable, still see the problem. I tried looking at `about:net-internals`, and as far as I could tell it looks fine. I am starting to thing it is not a network issue, but something to do with the `promises`, as I use them pretty heavily

Comment: I would suspect that in that case, the issue would surface in other browsers too. The other tabs in the timeline entry for the fetch may also provide some clues (_Bottom-Up_ and _Event Log_ are most useful, probably).

Comment: I have narrowed it down a bit more. It only happens when I scroll using my mousepad just before activating the link that does the transfer!

Comment: If I understand the timeline correctly, there _is_ an animation running during the same time that the fetch is taking place. Something hogging the event loop perhaps?

Comment: Hey @robertklep. Yeap! You understand it absolutely correctly! Removing the animation doesn't help however. I tried it :(

Comment: One more clue.. The problem goes away if I set `async` to `false`.

Comment: There's only 1 client thread in JavaScript, so anything else blocking the thread will cause a delay. Move the operation to a WebWorker and the delay will go away, because nothing else will be trying to execute asynchronously on that thread. However, the delay might move to waiting on the response from your WebWorker. :)

Comment: I'd love to make an answer for you, but you need to write a working example for it to be based on - without the context, an example may be pointless.

Comment: 1) Maybe this time need to open and close http connection?

Comment: I think it is either a bug in Chrome or in MDL. [Here](https://db.tt/22LpjpYm) is a minimal example where the problem is seen (it is written on elm, but I have seen the problem in plain JS as well). The only real code that I add is the XMLHTTPRequest.

Comment: @TylerY86 Thanks for the pointers to the WebWorker. Will give it a try!

Comment: Provided you with an example of using Fetch + WebWorker as an answer. Good luck.

Comment: Elm is outside the tags listed in the question. Could you provide a minimal JS example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a Chrome bug that has now been fixed in Chrome 54:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=649590#c1

Comment: I don't think anyone said in that bug that it was a bug, just that you couldn't reproduce it in Chrome 54. Are you sure it isn't something you changed? jan.boes...@gmail.com commented that it wasn't fixed, that your issues were different.

Comment: Nope, I didn't change anything. The same exact code works for Safari, Firefox and Chrome 54, but fails in chrome 53.

Answer (score 5):

I'm wagering since the latency goes away when you have `async: false` that it's due to something blocking the main thread.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xe5xyavv/6/), I get roughly 10 milliseconds for a simple request using Fetch inside of a WebWorker and posting the results back to the main thread.

```js
var workerBlobs = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("script[type=\"text\/js-worker\"]"), function (oScript) { return new Blob([oScript.textContent], {type: "text/javascript"}); });

var workers = workerBlobs.map(function(oBlob) { return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(oBlob)); });

var log = document.getElementById('log');

function println(s) {
  log.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s+'\n'));
}
workers[0].onmessage = function(oEvent) {
 println("Done in " + ( performance.now() - start ).toFixed(4) + "ms" );
  println(oEvent.data.message);
}
workers[0].onerror = function(oEvent) {
  println("Error: "+JSON.stringify(oEvent.data));
}

var start = performance.now();
workers[0].postMessage('http://stacksnippets.net/');
```

```css
#log {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/js-worker">
onmessage = function (oEvent) {
  fetch(oEvent.data).then(function(response) {
    response.text().then(function(text){
      console.log("response:",text);
      postMessage({ type: 'response', message: text });
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error("error:",err);
    postMessage({ type: 'error', message: err.toString(), stack: err.stack });
  });
}
</script>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

You'll have to excuse the error message when trying to execute; requests are somewhat cordoned inside that snippet sandbox. If I find a URL that works I'll throw it in. Use the [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/xe5xyavv/6/) example.

Edit: Updated [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/xe5xyavv/6/) example.
There is some minor latency penalty incurred when using postMessage (in this example, approximately 5ms in chrome). Same 10ms average total. This might be worked around using transferrable array buffers and some other shenanigans.

To be more clear about this, you should be able to use this example to perform your fetch and timing on your worker thread, and then see how long it takes to get back to your main thread. If it takes far too much time to go from worker to main, something is blocking in the main JS thread. Then you have to hunt that down, and introduce some async flow to allow interspersion with your fetching and such.